# Marketing Cloud Connect Storage

Tags: marketing-cloud, data-storage, marketing-cloud-connect, storage-limit

I am trying to find the storage amount that the Marketing Cloud Connect requires in SFDC. I know it creates 20 objects and I need to know how much space that will require.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the objects that you mention largely relate to Connector configuration and you don't really need to be concerned with this impacting your data limit.

However, the majority of data storage by Marketing Cloud is related to **email tracking data**, which you can estimate using the [Tracking Data Storage Calculator](https://help.marketingcloud.com/fr-CA/documentation/integrated_products__crm_and_web_analytic_solutions/marketing_cloud_connector_v5/tracking/tracking_data_storage_calculator/).

This storage amount can be significant, so you should consider also using the [Tracking Data Cleanup](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/integrated_products__crm_and_web_analytic_solutions/marketing_cloud_connector_v5/tracking/tracking_data_management/) feature to delete old email tracking data.

Comment: The link in your answer has gone 404. You can find a working storage calculator here: https://help.marketingcloud.com/fr-CA/documentation/integrated_products__crm_and_web_analytic_solutions/marketing_cloud_connector_v5/tracking/tracking_data_storage_calculator/

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the link in my answer!

Comment: The new link is now saying "site can't be reached". Anyone else having the same issue? Is there a new location for the calculator?

Comment: this image is still on the salesforce servers and used to be in that link. no guarantee for accuracy, but I saved this the first time around when the site moved. https://www.salesforce.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/rtaImage1.jpg